# postfixadmin can add only 10 virtual mailbox?

Tags: postfix

I setup successfully my mail-server using postfix + postfixadmin + mysql + cyrus + courier + squirrelmail 
Now I'm happy with it !
the last thing made me said is that I was limited to add virtual mailbox account.
when I use postfixadmin to add more than ten mailbox it said !

```
You have reached your limit to create mailboxes!
```

I only have ten mailbox _ _'

I don't know which configuration file or directive to edit ... Really need help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I'm assuming you probably fixed this I like to tie up lose ends.  You can easily increase the default 10 mailboxes by logging into postfix admin.  Then:

1. click Domain List
2. click "edit" at the far right
3. increase your mailboxes to any number or enter "0" for unlimited.
4. click "Edit Domain" to save

Comment: You can also change the default in the postfixadmin config file from 10 to something larger as well however changing that setting won't change it for domains already in the database.